# Docker 'Attaching ' exit with code 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lamp, amazon-linux

I'm trying to set up an amazonlinux lamp environment similar to:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

The build seems to go fine but when I get to the end I get:

```
Step 12/12 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in dd47b5479d0d
Removing intermediate container dd47b5479d0d
 ---> aa3ecf3ab25e
Successfully built aa3ecf3ab25e
Successfully tagged mrc_web:latest
Recreating my_webproject_1 ... done
Attaching to my_webproject_1
my_webproject_1 exited with code 0
```

For more details on file structure you can look at the github:
https://github.com/ericsemrow/basebox

My theory is that this is the volume attempting to mount and failing. More info on what is being attached would be appreciated and a resolution would me amazing!

Comment: It looks to me like your container is simply exiting normally (`exited with code 0`, indicates no error) because there is nothing for it to do, as your `ENTRYPOINT` is commented out.

Comment: Hot dang. I had been having an issue with it earlier so I commented it out. Thanks for taking a look and pointing that out!